# Content behind SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use a CustomScrollView and for children I have SliverAppBar and SliverList. So right now list is being rendered after app bar but my app bar is transparent and I would like list to be rendered under app bar (basically ignoring AppBar). Is it possible to do?

Comment: 'basically ignoring AppBar' does this mean you don't want AppBar to be displayed at all in your app ?

Comment: Sorry probably phrased it wrong. I meant I want appbar to be visible I just want SliverList to ignore the height of appbar and start from the very top behind appbar (like from the status bar).